# Remove Google Favicons In Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have ssl installed on my site. However I got this insecure icon  on the chrome's url bar. When I open the console I got this message:

```
The page at https://www.pm-sson.nl/index.php displayed insecure content from http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.mysite.com.
```

How can I remove this? I have my own favicon, but it doesn't remove it.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed in Google Chrome which are allowed to add content scripts to that page?

Comment: No problem. Content scripts from extensions can be a huge pain. You can start a **clean** browser instance by executing chrome with the switch `--user-data-dir="SOME_DIR_HERE"`. I usually use a temp folder.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify icon's url in your page.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href=”favicon.ico” />
```

Comment: I have this, but it keeps giving me that message

Comment: please search your page's html source code, find "http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=", see where reference this url. maybe in js file

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
      PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
[…]
</head>
[…]
</html>
that allow put your own favicon
```

Comment: Now I have <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico"> and <link rel="shortcut icon" href=”favicon.ico” /> but it still gives me the message.

Comment: See comment from Jim Schubert in the question for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The SEO Meta Inspector extension will apparently cause this problem. See

[Google Product Forums matching issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/analytics/W3KKl3H1gjo)

Fritz